# Understanding Transceiver vs buffer

Tags: circuit-design, components, datasheet

Using this [OctoWS2811](https://www.pjrc.com/store/octo28_adaptor.html) as an example, when to use a transceiver vs buffer?

[image: OctoWS2811]

It uses an 74HCT245 (bus transceiver) with the direction tied high.
Why not use a line driver like 74HCT541 (buffer)? Specs look very similar other then a few nanoseconds here and there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could use either part (or any of a number of similar ones). The 74HCT541 would work equally well.

Often there are reasons that go beyond technical though.  For example:

1. Cost - one may be cheaper
2. Availability - the other part may have a long lead time or are already in stock.
3. Minimization of number of parts in design - it is often desirable to reduce the number of different part numbers in a design. Especially this may useful to reduce the setup in the pick and place machine.
4. Commonality of design - using the same parts as on other designs

Comment: That is what I was thinking too. I want to reduce the number of parts and go with all same buffers in my circuit. Since I don't need the bi-direction of the bus. Was just looking at commonality of designs and came across the 74__245 a bunch of times.    -Thank you Kevin.